# Container BorderRadius.circular Doesnt work (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

I want to border the edges of my image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj0O5.png)

But although I add decoration to my code, but borders code doesnt work. Can you tell me where I went wrong?
here is my code;

```
 Container(
                              height: 130,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    MaterialButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {},
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            'Call Center',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Center(
                                      child: MaterialButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pushNamed(
                                              context, ContactUsPage.routeName);
                                        },
                                        padding:
                                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              'WhatsApp',
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
```

Comment: Any ideas? Did I ask the question wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `showBottomSheet()` to show this ? If so, there is a `shape` parameter to it.